# Unable to use SSD as boot drive

Tags: boot, installation, ssd, bios, acer-aspire

I own an Acer Aspire Predator G3620 and bought a Samsung EVO 840 SSD to speed up my performance. Unfortunately, after plugging in the SSD into my pc, the BIOS does not allow me to use the SSD as boot device.

Currently I have reinstalled Windows 8.1 on my old hard drive and I'm using my SSD for my virtual memory paging file and game installs.

The BIOS of this pc looks very limited though, even when I go to the advanced settings...

Has anyone had the same issue and does anyone have a solution for this?